# error while executing bib tex on misc item

Tags: bibtex, abbrvnat.bst

I am writting the bib tex. i give error while executing the code

```
@misc{link:group_thm,
title={MA426: Elliptic Curves},
author={Anni, Samuele},
year={2015},
publisher={April}
}
```

It give error message

```
Database file #1: my_bib.bib
ptr=1, stack=
S.~Anni
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry link:group_thm
while executing---line 1435 of file abbrvnat.bst
```

Please give me solution of this problem.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: and have a look at [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: `_` is a special char for TeX, you can't use it in a name of a item, remove it from `link:group_thm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Because you gave no MWE it is hard to help you. To get you started please see the following MWE (I used package `filecontents` only to have TeX code and bib file together in a compilable MWE) `mwe.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@misc{link:group_thm,
  title     = {MA426: Elliptic Curves},
  author    = {Anni, Samuele},
  year      = {2015},
  publisher = {April},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{link:group_thm} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} 

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

This MWE compiles with the compile chain `pdflatex mwe.tex` -- `bibtex mwe` -- `pdflatex mwe.tex` -- `pdflatex mwe.tex` without errors to:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Now please compare my given MWE with your code and change the mwe to reproduce your error.  BTW: Is the used style file `abbrvnat.bst` the standard one? Did you load other packages influencing the bibliography? If yes add them to a new mwe and add this mwe to your question!